# About qsort in C for string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, qsort

I'm trying to sort a string array in alphabetized order using `qsort`.

When I use `comp1`, which casts the arguments to `char**`, it works well.
But not if I use `comp2`, which casts to `char*` instead.

Why? I can't understand the difference between `comp1` and `comp2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp1(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char **pa = (const char **)a;
    const char **pb = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*pa, *pb);
}
int comp2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const char *pa = (const char *)a;
    const char *pb = (const char *)b;
    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}
void main(void) {
    char *array[] = {"c","b","a"};
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(char *);
    int i;
    qsort(array,size,sizeof(char *),compX);
    //compX is comp1 or comp2
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%s",array[i]);
    }
}
```

outputs

abc ←　when I use comp1

cba ←　when I use comp2

Comment: As an aside, it's `int main` And explicit casts from `void*` to some other data-pointer-type are not needed and should not be done in C. Also, avoid passing a type to `sizeof` instead of an expression, that's error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is an array of pointers to strings.
As the comparator-function always gets pointers to the starts of the elements sorted, that means it gets `void*` which **point to** `char*` to those strings.

Casting those `void*` to `char*` is obviously one indirection too few.

Comment: Oh,I've understood!char*'s pointer is char**.Thanks!